# isset returning a '1'

Tags: php, html, isset

New to PHP, keep that in mind.

My question:

I have a checkbox setup, however when someone clicks a checkbox it returns a '1' instead of the value. How do I fix this?

```
    <td valign="top">Kies minimaal 1 tijdschrift:</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="gamez" value="gamez" />Stuur mij informatie over het tijdschrijft GAMEZ<br />

$gamez = (isset($_POST["gamez"]) ?
    true : false);

    echo("<tr><td>Tijdschriften:</td><td>$gamez $girls $uitgaan $mode</td></tr></table>");
```

When I check gamez for instance, it shows:
Tijdschriften:  1

Comment: `$option1` is not defined.

Comment: dont set value attribute, then see what you get

Comment: `$option1` seems to be defined, just not like it is needed.

Comment: A boolean converted to a string will be `1` for "true" and `(empty)` for "false".

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You are writing `true` into it, which is cast to string "1" when you `echo` it. Write the value in it:

```
$option1 = (isset($_POST["option1"]) ? $_POST["option1"] : false);
echo("<tr><td>Options:</td><td>$option1</td></tr></table>");
```

Note that when `$_POST["option1"]` is not set, `$option1` is `false`, which when `echo`'d is cast to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["option1"]))
{
$option1=$_POST["option1"];
echo "<tr><td>Options:</td><td>$option1</td></tr></table>"; //echo not a function
}
else
{



}
```

Answer (score 0):

its true.you are writting true

```
*if(isset($_post['option1'] )
{
$option1=$post["option1"];
echo("<tr><td>options:</td><td></tr></table>");
}*
```

note that when $_post["option1] is not set